# Let's get critical: Jun 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Craft CMS Stack Exchange](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Lol, who would downvote this?

Comment: @LindseyD Those who boldly stand against self-evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Inline and multiline comments in Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/inline-and-multiline-comments-in-craft)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Dukt Twitter plugin float issue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9637/dukt-twitter-plugin-float-issue)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Paginate by Group](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/paginate-by-group)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I show 3 entries at random from within the next 10](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9578/how-can-i-show-3-entries-at-random-from-within-the-next-10)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Google Map setup for markers](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/google-map-setup-for-markers)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to save extra data when I save an entry](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9230/how-to-save-extra-data-when-i-save-an-entry)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Translate field name displayed within validation error messages?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9716/translate-field-name-displayed-within-validation-error-messages)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Namespace issues when calling a plugin variable](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9692/namespace-issues-when-calling-a-plugin-variable)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Get entries that's not already listed](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/get-entries-thats-not-already-listed)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Caching and Rendering](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/caching-and-rendering)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---